# Alternative to importing django models in __init__, but make them available in module namespace

Tags: python, django

I have a package which has several Classes:

```
package
    __init__.py
    Class1.py
    Class2.py
    Class3.py
```

In my `__init__.py`, I import the classes as follows:

```
from .Class1 import Class1
from .Class2 import Class2
```

so that I can access those objects like this:

```
import package
class1 = package.Class1()
class2 = package.Class2()
```

instead of this:

```
from package.Class1 import Class1
from package.Class2 import Class2
class1 = package.Class1()
class2 = package.Class2()
```

However, since django 1.9, models shouldn't be imported in the `__init__` or the following exception is thrown:
`django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`

I'm wondering if there's a way to reorganize this but maintain the same functionality?

Comment: Why specifically do you have the models in separate files?

Comment: Is there any good reason you don't place the models in `models.py` where they are supposed to be?

Comment: Each class can be used independently, so I thought it was clearer structurally. I could put the all in the init, but then I'll run into the same problem of defining models in __init__

Comment: Klaus, this isn't a django package. I'm just trying to use the django ORM.

Comment: To add a bit more detail. I have a base package that I've built in python-only - referred to here as 'package'. I also have a django site, which heavily uses this package for its back-end logic. I import the base 'package' in the settings.py app in my django site.

However, I plan on using the django orm both with my django site, and with the base python package